# Appending to every printed message

Tags: python, pretty-print

Simple question, I would like to append text to the front of every `print` I call, for example if I set the text to `hello` and ran this:

```
print 'hello there'
print ' hi again'
```

It would print this:

```
hellohello there
hello hi again
```

Is there any way of doing this, without using a function to use that instead of `print`?

Comment: "stylize the printing" not sure I understand this part, could you please rephrase?

Comment: I meant creating a function that just called `print 'hello' + message`, I would like to edit the actual `print` command.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid making a function for this? Something like `def myPrint(text): print('hello '+text`) is really the way to go for this.

Comment: @Junuxx - Because I would _prefer_ to use `print` instead of another function to print.

Comment: @user1447941: I've used function names like 'log()' or 'say()' in similar situations. While people may offer you hackish solutions to redefine `print`, I would really advise you not to do that. It's only going to cause problems and confusions later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override print as per [DevPlayer's post here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10106489/15369), slightly modified here:

```
from __future__ import print_function
# Note: If you are using Python 3 leave this line out
# This must be the first statement before other statements.
# You may only put a quoted or triple quoted string, 
# Python comments or blank lines before the __future__ line.
import sys

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    """My custom print() function."""
    # Adding new arguments to the print function signature 
    # is probably a bad idea.
    # Instead consider testing if custom argument keywords
    # are present in kwargs
    sys.stdout.write('hello')
    return __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)

print ("hello there")
print (" hi again")
```

**[Edit]** ...or as DSM suggests, you could avoid the sys call with this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
# Note: If you are using Python 3 leave this line out
# This must be the first statement before other statements.
# You may only put a quoted or triple quoted string, 
# Python comments or blank lines before the __future__ line.

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    """My custom print() function."""
    # Adding new arguments to the print function signature 
    # is probably a bad idea.
    # Instead consider testing if custom argument keywords
    # are present in kwargs
    __builtins__.print('hello',end='')
    return __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)

print ("hello there")
print (" hi again")
```

Comment: This just prints the `hello` on a new line before every `print` I call.

Comment: Rather than using `sys.stdout.write`, you could just pass the `end=''` argument to the print function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change Python 2's print statement, but you can write your own file-like object and use it:

```
class PrefixedFile(object):
    def __init__(self, f, prefix):
        self.f = f
        self.prefix = prefix

    def write(self, s):
        s = s.replace("\n", "\n"+self.prefix)
        self.f.write(s)

sys.stdout = PrefixedFile(sys.stdout, "hello: ")

print "One"
print "Two"
```

Note this code doesn't quite work because it missing a prefix on the very first line, and adds one at the very end, but you get the idea! :)

Comment: @JonCage: You can change the print *function*, but changing the print *statement* is not easily done.

Comment: Yeah, okay, you got me there :-)

Comment: @Ned: Do you know what the community recommends, when it comes to replacing `sys.stdout`? `print` behaves behind the scenes, in a non-explicit way, when `sys.stdout` is replaced… I tend to prefer introducing my own print function instead of replacing `sys.stdout`, or maybe use the logging module, if appropriate. I would only replace `sys.stdout` as an afterthought.

Comment: I agree that replacing sys.stdout is a blunt instrument, and better would be to use the logging module or a custom print-like function.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Jon Cage's answer is a good way of replacing the `print()` function, I would advise to instead use your own print function (using Jon's code):

```
from __future__ import print_function
# Note: If you are using Python 3 leave this line out
# This must be the first statement before other statements.
# You may only put a quoted or triple quoted string, 
# Python comments or blank lines before the __future__ line.

def my_print(*args, **kwargs):
    """My custom print() function."""
    # Adding new arguments to the print function signature 
    # is probably a bad idea.
    # Instead consider testing if custom argument keywords
    # are present in kwargs
    print('hello', end='')
    print(*args, **kwargs)
```

The only difference with Jon's answer is that you *do not override the built-in* `print()` ("monkey patching"). I advocate this instead of modifying `print()` because this makes your code more maintainable, as everybody expects `print()` to be the built-in one.

Using the `print()` *function* instead of the `print` statement, in `my_print()`, gives [greater flexibility](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print).

Comment: I agree that using a differently named function is much safer, but that's not what the OP asked for ;-)

Comment: @JonCage: Yeah, he asked for a replacement of the print *statement*, and none of the answers offers this, because this is hard. :)