# Changing the definition of an existing function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print to a file using `print` I import from `__future___`. I have the following as an import:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

From now on, I can print using:

```
print("stuff", file=my_handle)
```

However, I have many calls to `print` in a function, so I would want to be able to use a function where the keyword argument is bound to `my_handle`. So, I use partial application:

```
printfile = partial(print, file=my_handle)
printfile("stuff")
printfile("more stuff")
```

which is what I intended. However, is there any way I can change to definition of `print` itself by partially applying the keyword argument? What I have tried was:

```
print = partial(print, file=my_handle)
```

however I got an error saying:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment
```

Is there any way to use `print` without mentioning my file every time?

Comment: What about `print = printfile`? Seems to work for me.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. If I do that, I still get the same error, which shows me the `printfile = ...` line, saying that print is unbound.

Comment: Is this relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550470/overload-print-python ?

Comment: @loudandclear: `print = printfile` and `print = partial(print, file=my_handle)` both work for me, with Python 2.7.4. There must be something else wrong...

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Python 2.7.3, can that be the reason?

Comment: @fsw: The second answer actually is, however I can't make that function work too (see my comment under the second answer there).

Answer (score 0):

`print = partial(print, file=my_handle)`

This line causes the UnboundLocalError on the second `print`, the one used as argument to `partial()`.  This is because the name `print` is found to be a local variable in this particular function --- because you assign to it, in this case in the same line, more generally in the same function.  You can't use the same variable name in one function to refer sometimes to a global and sometimes to a local.

To fix it you need to use a different name:

`fprint = partial(print, file=my_handle)`.