# Inheritance and customisation of class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I define one class `Device` with lot of subclasses like for example `Microcontroller`.

Device has two mode and especially the "simulated" mode.

I am trying to code `Device` class such has if `Microcontroller` is in simulated mode then when a print is performed it should prefix the string by `[simulated]`:

```
print "Hey !!"
> [simulated] Hey!!
```

I don't know how to start and if it's possible to overload `print`.

Comment: You're going to need to create your own print function that checks if Microcontroller is in simulator made, and if so, adds the necessary prefix.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to overload print ? (like for operator)

Comment: @Katsu you can't overload print as a statement, you have to do a function yourself.

Comment: That's what `__repr__` is for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python

Comment: @Katsu Overloading print is only possible in Python 3.x. See this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550470/overload-print-python If you are using Python 2.x (which it looks like) then you can use a stdout hook or logging to achieve similar effects.

Comment: @JohnDoe How does `__repr__` help here? `repr` is for representing objects, not overloading the `print` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement some logger class, and use it for logging. You can do dome object injection to replace the type of logger when you want. For example:

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix
    def log(self, msg):
        print('[{}] {}'.format(self.prefix, msg))


class Base:
    def set_logger(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger


class Test(Base):
    def do_something(self):
        self.logger.log('Hey !!')


test = Test()

test.set_logger(Logger('simulated'))
test.do_something()

test.set_logger(Logger('very real'))
test.do_something()
```

for example:

```
[simulated] Hey !!
[very real] Hey !!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this answer by suggesting that you never use this approach in real code. However, for completeness (and as it answers the original question) I thought I would add it here.

So you can redirect and catch `print` statements on the fly by redirecting `sys.stdout`.

You can start by defining a file-like object that catches `stdout` and redirects to... `stdout`.

```
import sys

class OutputFormatter(object):
    def __init__(self,prefix="",suffix=""):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.suffix = suffix

    def write(self,msg):

        # As you want to change the behaviour of the print statement,
        # you need to ignore solitary newlines that are sent to stdout

        if msg != '\n':

           # reformat the message passed by print
            msg = " ".join([self.prefix,msg,self.suffix])

        # redirect back to stdout
        sys.__stdout__.write(msg)
```

With this in place, you can use it to replace `sys.stdout` to produce the "overridden" type of print behaviour you describe.

```
class Device(object):
    def set_simulated(self):
        # in simulated mode, use the stdout redirect
        sys.stdout = OutputFormatter(prefix="[simulated]",suffix="")

    def set_real(self):
        # in real mode make sure to return to proper stdout
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


class Microcontroller(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Microcontroller,self).__init__()
        self.set_simulated()    
        print "This is simulated"

        self.set_real()
        print "This is real"

Microcontroller()
```

This will print the following to the terminal:

```
[simulated] This is simulated 
This is real
```

Beware however that this is a global change to the behaviour of `stdout` and will affect all print statements if a `Device` subclass has been set to simulated mode.

A much better approach for systems like this where you require context dependent messages is to use the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) or to take the approach suggested by BSH.