# why importing a module clashes with overridden print?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to automatically add a timestamp to my `print` statements (in Python 2.x) [by overriding it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10106489/903011). It works, except when I import a module which also contains the override.

My main file `testa.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import testb

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    __builtins__.print(datetime.datetime.now(), ' ', end='')
    return __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)

print("from main file")
testb.MyClass()
```

The helper file `testb.py`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    __builtins__.print(datetime.datetime.now(), ' ', end='')
    return __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        print("from helper file")
```

When running testa:

```
2014-07-29 09:43:54.375000  from main file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/testa.py", line 10, in <module>
    testb.MyClass()
  File "C:\testb.py", line 15, in __init__
    print("from helper file")
  File "C:\testb.py", line 10, in print
    __builtins__.print(datetime.datetime.now(), ' ', end='')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'print'
```

I think that when importing `testb`, its `print` definition somehow clashes with the one in `testa` but this is where my thinking reaches its limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not rely on the `__builtins__`. Instead, `import __builtin__` and use `__builtin__.print`. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html

> By default, when in the `__main__` module, `__builtins__` is the built-in module `__builtin__` (note: no ‘s’); when in any other module, `__builtins__` is an alias for the dictionary of the `__builtin__` module itself.
>
> CPython implementation detail: Users should not touch `__builtins__`; it
>   is strictly an implementation detail. Users wanting to override values
>   in the builtins namespace should import the `__builtin__` (no ‘s’)
>   module and modify its attributes appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way to make this work but I suggest to look at the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) instead.

`print()` is a nice little helper for you basic "output text" needs. Logging is much more powerful, it can add time stamps and "where was this printed" information to the output.

Comment: I know the logging module and use it as well. The specific situation I face with my program (which is in debugging phase) drove me into overriding `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't look too bad (though the DRY principle is being violated). It appears you have made an assignment (of a dict value) to the name **builtins**, which in my 2.7 installation is a module not a dict. But you haven't.

```
airhead:~ sholden$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 19 2013, 03:12:29)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> __builtins__
<module '__builtin__' (built-in)>
>>>
```

@rczajka give you the correct answer, which I've upvoted.