# change value of default argument of a python bultin function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to change the default value of arguments of the print function ?

particularly these arguments:

```
file=sys.stdout
flush=False
```

For example throughout my code I would like to toggle between `flush=True` and `flush=False` without having to manually add the argument value to every print statement I have. Preferably by adding 1 line of code vs going to every print function and manually changing the value of the argument.

Comment: Is it an interactive program? How are you planning on toggling it without explicitly writing so in the program?

Comment: create new function passing those arguments then you can use that function

Comment: Create Function for Custom Print and call that every time instead of Print

Comment: is there no way using something like `.func_defaults` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overload print function to expand its functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621655/how-to-overload-print-function-to-expand-its-functionality)

Comment: You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to define your own prints: `print_flush = partial(print, flush=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to override defaults:

```py
from functools import partial

print_and_flush = partial(print, flush=True)
```

Then you can switch between using `print` and `print_and_flush`.

Alternatively, you can get your behavior by defining a custom class:

```py
class CustomPrinter:
    def __init__(self, print_func):
        self.print = print_func
        self.flush = False

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('flush', self.flush)
        return self.print(*args, **kwargs)


print = CustomPrinter(print)
print('foo')
print.flush = True
print('bar')
```

Comment: Advice to OP: this kind of code makes it hard to understand and follow (when looking at a certain print statement you don't know if it is flushed or not). Either stick to the first option presented in this answer (`partial`) or to explicit arguments.

Comment: @Tomerikoo definitely, that is also why i didn't want to write another function which uses print in the first place

Comment: @AnarKi another function can be fine, consider you have functions like `print_and_flush` or `print_without_flush` that's pretty clear to an unfamiliar reader even without going to the definition...

Comment: @Tomerikoo actually i ended up “redefining” print with the partial function literally as in print = partial(print, flush=True). This was exactly what i wanted