# Why can't Python find the built-in print function when calling from an imported function?

Tags: python

Take this **main.py**:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from sub import print

print("hello, world")
```

and this **sub.py**:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    return __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using Python 2.7.9, run `main.py` and you get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    print("hello, world")
File "/Users/ien/Studio/songifier/sub.py", line 4, in print
    return __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'print'
```

Why and how to make this work?

NOTE: This is an artificial example to isolate the problem, which has arisen in a logging context, where the `print` function sometimes does some fancy logging, and other times wants to just call the built-in print function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import __builtin__
from __future__ import print_function

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    return __builtin__.print(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

```
>>> print
<function print at 0x7f80cd622668>
>>> print("Hello", "world", sep="\n")
Hello
world
```

The reason for the error you were seeing can be explained better by this excerpt from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html):

> By default, when in the `__main__` module, `__builtins__` is the
>   built-in module `__builtin__` (note: no 's'); when in any other
>   module, `__builtins__` is an alias for the dictionary of the
>   `__builtin__` module itself.
>
> `__builtins__` can be set to a user-created dictionary to create a
>   weak form of restricted execution.
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** Users should not touch `__builtins__`; it is strictly an implementation detail.  Users
>   wanting to override values in the builtins namespace should `import`
>   the `__builtin__` (no 's') module and modify its attributes
>   appropriately. The namespace for a module is automatically created the
>   first time a module is imported.

Answer (score -1):

To quote an answer on this question:
[overload print python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550470/overload-print-python)

> In Python 2.x you can't, because print isn't a function, it's a
>   statement. In Python 3 print is a function, so I suppose it could be
>   overridden (haven't tried it, though).