# extending list without spaces in python

Tags: python, list

I want to add numbers to a pre-existing list and preserve no spacing between comma separated values but when I use the extend function in python, it adds spaces.

Input:

```
x=[2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7]
```

Run:

```
x.extend(y)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Desired output:

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to keep its type when printing, You can convert the type of variables with str() and replace whitespaces to `''`.

```
x=[2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7]
x.extend(y)
x_removed_whitespaces = str(x).replace(' ', '')
print(x_removed_whitespaces)
```

output:

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, lists are printed in that specific way.

```
>>> x = [2,3,4]
>>> print(x)
>>> [2, 3, 4]
```

If you want the print function to print the lists in some other way, then you would have to change/override the print method manually, and then specify how you want to print the list. It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550470/overload-print-python).

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own function that prints the list the way you want:

```
def printList(aList):
    print('['+",".join(map(str,aList))+']')

x=[2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7]
x.extend(y)
printList(x)
```

Output:

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```