# Python - tie built in function to created function

Tags: python, printing

I want to keep track of the last time my python program printed something to the console.

I created this function:

```
def updateLastPrintTime():
    global lastPrintTime
    lastPrintTime = time.time()
```

And I'm calling it after each print statement.

This works fine, however, I have a lot of print statements and I want to update `lastPrintTime` after each and every printing.

If `print` was not a built in function, this is what I would do:

```
def print():
    updateLastPrintTime()
    # rest of 'print' code ...
```

But I can't figure out how to do that with a built-in function, especially since they are written in C.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer: [overload print python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550470/overload-print-python)

You could do something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time

last_print_time = time.time()  # initialise global var

try:
    import __builtin__
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    import builtins as __builtin__

# overload the print function
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    global last_print_time
    last_print_time = time.time()  # update variable
    return __builtin__.print(*args, **kwargs)  # print the message
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the builtins `print` to another name and then you can override `print`

```
_print = print
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    _print("Hello,", *args, **kwargs)

print("world!")
```

Alternatively, you can also get the builtins print from the `builtins` module e.g.

```
import builtins
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    builtins.print("Hello,", *args, **kwargs)

print("world!")
```

Comment: This is the direction that I'm looking for, but both are giving me ```invalid syntax``` on lines ```def print(*args, **kwargs):``` and ```_print = print```

Comment: @Sky what version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: @Sky, ok your description of `print` as a function confused me. You should look at the answer from @Dan below (or the linked answer). The answer I gave only works for python 3.